# Jquery Pagination on ajax loaded data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a listing according to the categories. I am loading the data listing using jquery post. On the ajax loaded data I am looking for a pagination using ajax again. Please suggest me with the best solutions.

What i have thought of is to make three  with different ids and load when clicked on categories then again call a function onclick of the pagination nos to replace contents of ajaxloaded  div like..

```
<div id='data'> 
   <div id='ajaxloaded'>
      data listing goes herez
   </div> 
     <div id='paginate'> 1 2 3..</div>
 </div>
```

Is this the way to go for it ? anyone got a better idea please suggest me some
I am using PHP and Mysql.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can use datatables http://datatables.net/

Comment: 10 jquery pagination plugins http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/#.T9iNICse6U4

Comment: i am using jquery pagination plugins on other pages. Here shall i load the entire table with table headers, data and pagination onclick of categories

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataTables](http://datatables.net), it's a jQuery library allowing pagination.

Look at [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of these? 
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Comment: i was implementing the functionality in the ajax response with pagination list onclick it's not able to get the div id "ajaxloaded"

Comment: Its difficult to envision the issues with such a vague information. would appreciate if you create a demo on jsfiddle.net.